# Type-generic queue implementation using singly linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

Simple lightweight queue implementation using data size registration and singly linked lists as the underlying type

[Update #2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278626/rev-2-type-generic-queue-implementation-using-singly-linked-lists)

````c
/*
    Author: Jared Thomas
    Date:   Tuesday, August 2, 2022
    
    Type-generic queue using singly linked lists
*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node {
    void *          data;
    struct Node *   next;
} Node;

typedef struct Queue {
    Node *  head;
    size_t  data_size;
} Queue;

typedef struct Person {
    char const *        name;
    unsigned short int  age;
    char const *        occupation;
} Person;

Queue *create_queue();
void register_new_size(Queue *, size_t data_size);
void enqueue(Queue *, void *data);
void *front(Queue *);
int length(Queue *);
int is_empty(Queue *);
void dequeue(Queue *);
Queue *copy_queue(Queue *);
void print(Queue *);
void destroy_queue(Queue *);

int is_empty(Queue *b)
{
    if(b->head == NULL) { return 1; }
    return 0;
}

Queue *create_queue()
{
    Queue *new_queue = (Queue *)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    new_queue->head = NULL;
    return new_queue;
}

void destroy_queue(Queue *b)
{
    while(!is_empty(b)) {
        dequeue(b);
    }
    free(b);
}

void enqueue(Queue *b, void *data)
{
    Node *new_node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new_node->data = malloc(b->data_size);
    memcpy(new_node->data, data, b->data_size);
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if(is_empty(b)) {
        b->head = new_node;
        return;
    }
    Node *n = b->head;
    while(n->next != NULL) {
        n = n->next;
    }
    n->next = new_node;
}

void *front(Queue *b)
{
    return (b->head)->data;
}

int length(Queue *b)
{
    Queue *copy = create_queue();
    register_new_size(copy, b->data_size);
    int count = 0;
    while(!is_empty(b)) {
        enqueue(copy, front(b));
        dequeue(b);
        count++;
    }
    while(!is_empty(copy)) {
        enqueue(b, front(copy));
        dequeue(copy);
    }
    destroy_queue(copy);
    return count;
}

void dequeue(Queue *b)
{
    Node *upcoming = b->head->next;
    free(b->head);
    b->head = NULL;
    if(upcoming != NULL) {
        b->head = upcoming;
    }
}

Queue *copy_queue(Queue *b)
{
    Queue *copy = create_queue();
    register_new_size(copy, b->data_size);
    int count = length(b);
    while(count > 0) {
        void *d = front(b);
        enqueue(copy, d);
        dequeue(b);
        enqueue(b, d);
        count--;
    }
    return copy;
}

void print(Queue *b)
{
    if(is_empty(b)) {
        printf("[empty]\n");
        return;
    }
    Queue *copy = copy_queue(b);
    printf("[");
    while(!is_empty(copy)) {
        struct Person *d = (struct Person *)front(copy);
        printf("%s, ", d->name);
        dequeue(copy);
    }
    printf("]");
    printf("\n");
    destroy_queue(copy);
}

void register_new_size(Queue *b, size_t data_size)
{
    b->data_size = data_size;
}

int main(void)
{
    Queue *queue = create_queue();
    Person chase = { "Chase", 49, "Banker" };
    Person evan  = { "Evan", 34, "Doctor" };
    Person susie = { "Susie", 43, "Teacher" };
    register_new_size(queue, sizeof(Person));
    enqueue(queue, &chase);
    enqueue(queue, &evan);
    enqueue(queue, &susie);
    print(queue);
    dequeue(queue);
    print(queue);
    dequeue(queue);
    print(queue);
    dequeue(queue);
    print(queue);
    destroy_queue(queue);
    return 0;
}

```
````

Comment: I've since realized that I'm not checking for ```malloc()``` returning ```NULL```

Comment: Just a minor tip that doesn't feel like it warrants a separate answer: I would suggest that `dequeue` returns the dequeued data. It allows for use cases like `while( data = queue->dequeue() ) { /* do something with data */ )`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Yes, you don't check the malloc return value. Along the same line, you should not cast it.
- `is_empty` implementation is anti-idiomatic. It should be

  ```
    return b->head == NULL;
  ```
- `dequeue` from an empty queue dereferences `NULL`.
- `register_new_size` is called uncontrollably, and has no relation to the size of the next data item to be enqueued. You'd be in much less eror prone having

  ```
    typedef struct Node {
        void * data;
        size_t size;
        Node * next;
    };
  ```

  and

  ```
    void enqueue(Queue * b, void * data,  size_t data_size);
  ```
- `length` is scarily suboptimal. There is no need create a copy. Consider

  ```
    size_t length(Queue * b)
    {
         size_t len = 0;
         Node * cursor = b->head;
         while (cursor) {
             len++;
             cursor = cursor->next;
         }
         return len;
    }
  ```

  Better yet, make `size` a member of `Queue`; increment it on each enqueueing, and decrement it in each dequeuing.

  BTW, notice the type. `int` may not be wide enough.
- `print_queue` has a very limited utility. Consider a more generic

  ```
    map(Function f, Queue * q, void * args)
    {
        Node * cursor = q->head;
        while (cursor) {
            f(cursor->data, args);
        }
    }
  ```

  where `Function` should be declared along the lines of

  ```
    typedef void (*Function)(void *, void *);
  ```

  As a side note, there are plenty of variations of the theme.
- `enqueue` has a linear time complexity. Keeping a `tail` pointer is a small price to make it constant time (just enqueue at the tail, and dequeue from the head).

Answer (score 9):

Don't cast the result value of `malloc()`. (In general, using casts in C is a yellow card. Using C-style casts in C++ is a red card)

The reason to cast the result of `malloc()` is because C++ requires a cast for `malloc()`, but C doesn't require that.

1. Using `malloc()` in C++ is already a red flag, so you don't need to cast the result of `malloc()`
2. In C, casting the result of `malloc()` is actually very harmful.

If you forgot to include `<stdlib.h>` and you ignore compiler warnings, the result type of `malloc()` would be implicit `int`, so you will cast `int` to `Queue*`, god knows what will happen. This kind of bug is very hard to spot. If you don't cast, then implicit casting from `int` to `Queue*` is not allowed, so the compiler will reject your code for you.

Answer (score 6):

You've already mentioned in the comments that you should be checking the return value of `malloc` so I won't mention that further.

1. To start off with a minor point, since `create_queue` doesn't take any arguments, you should mark this explicitly via

```c
Queue *create_queue(void);
```

Also, this function leaves the `item_size` field uninitialized.  You should either have a default value or pass the desired value as an argument.

2. Since `enqueue` adds items to the end, it would be more efficient to add a `tail` field to `Queue`.  That way, you don't need to seek to the end of
   the list every time you add something.
3. The function `is_empty` can be simplified to

```c
int is_empty(const Queue *b)
{
    return (b->head == NULL);
}
```

since boolean expressions always have the numerical value 1 or 0.  Note that I've marked the argument as `const` as well.

You could even make it a macro:

```c
#define QUEUE_IS_EMPTY(b) ((b)->head == NULL)
```

4. With `destroy_queue`, you call `free(b)` at the end.  That may be fine but consider if you want to allow queues to be created on the stack.  I.e.,

```c
Queue b;
```

If so, then you should remove the call to `free` from `destroy_queue` and have that be a separate operation.

5. You should be checking the arguments of all non-static functions.  What if `data` is `NULL` in `enqueue`?  You'd crash with a segfault.
6. This is minor but I recommend changing the name of the `Queue*` variables to something other than `b`.  Variable names, with the exception of `for` loop indices, should be descriptive.  `queue` would be a good choice.  If you want to use a single letter, why not `q`?

Comment: +1 for all the good points, but I would not have suggested making a macro.

Comment: Why would you not use a macro?

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104568/macro-vs-function-in-c) for the various pitfalls of macros. Even if your macro looks fine, consider that it doesn't have any type checking (you can apply it to anything that has a `head` member variable), and it pollutes the global namespace (what if you have implemented other containers that also need an `IS_EMPTY()` function?).

Comment: Adding an `assert()` or two would not go amiss, but checking pointers point to the appropriate kind and amount of data is generally impossible to check.

Comment: Perhaps an inline function?

Answer (score 3):

I later discovered this revision contains a serious error, which is dequeueing frees the space occupied by the head node, but does not first free the space occupied by the head node's data, which leaves the memory block hanging without a reference to it; this is a memory leak.